# Adding objects together in R (like ggplot layers)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing OOP R and was wondering how to make it so the `+` can be used to add custom objects together. The most common example of this I've found is in `ggplot2` w/ adding geoms together.

I read through the `ggplot2` source code and found this

https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/plot-construction.r

It looks like `"%+%"` is being used, but it's not clear how that eventually translates into the plain `+` operator.

Comment: This is sort of above my level of comprehension, but line 63 in the attached seems to define a method for `+` to be dispatched on `gg` objects. `methods("+")` confirms there is a method for `gg`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to define a method for the generic function `+`. (At the link in your question, that method is `"+.gg"`, designed to be dispatched by arguments of class `"gg"`). :

```
## Example data of a couple different classes
dd <- mtcars[1, 1:4]
mm <- as.matrix(dd)

## Define method to be dispatched when one of its arguments has class data.frame
`+.data.frame` <- function(x,y) rbind(x,y)

## Any of the following three calls will dispatch the method
dd + dd
#            mpg cyl disp  hp
# Mazda RX4   21   6  160 110
# Mazda RX41  21   6  160 110
dd + mm
#            mpg cyl disp  hp
# Mazda RX4   21   6  160 110
# Mazda RX41  21   6  160 110
mm + dd
#            mpg cyl disp  hp
# Mazda RX4   21   6  160 110
# Mazda RX41  21   6  160 110
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, do you know where this is in the R docs?

Comment: @Greg -- I don't think it *is* directly in the R docs. You actually did the best thing by going straight to the sources of the function you were interested in. It also would've worked to try `methods("+")` and then have had a look at `+.Date` or `+.POSIXt` or `+.gg` (if **ggplot2** was loaded). In any case, glad this helped.

Comment: Just as a follow-up because this is beyond my level of comprehension: how would I use `+.gg*` to add ggproto objects together? Let's say I'd like to save some scale aes for later like `my.scale_aes <- scale_x_continuous(...) + scale_color_manual(...)`. How would I do this now that I have `+.gg*`?